# Angular4 AOT Routes failing

Tags: javascript, angular

When i am bulding  my app with key -aot all routes fail.
Routes work in JIT mode just fine, but in AOT mode every route fails except for the main page and 404.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
{
    path: '',
    component: FakeMainPageComponent
},
{
    path: '**',
    component: NotPAgeComponent
},
{
    path: 'admin',
    component: FakeAdminComponent
}])
```

Application itself compiles without any errors at all.

Comment: Are you using `loadChildren` to include any sub-routing module somewhere?

Comment: you must put the route with `**` path last.

Comment: No, i am not using lazy loading